# Laravel Object queries - 3 tables

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I have three tables like this:

```
**Users**
id

**Posts**
id
user_id

**Favorites**
id
user_id
post_id
```

Currently, I made it so when I query my posts for display, it pulls all the related user data who created the post with that row which is great! But what I'm trying to do now is also add to see if the user Authorized (Logged in) has favorited the post (row) so I can display to that they already favorited it. I don't want to re-query for every post (i think its called the N+1 problem?). I'm using Laravel4

**Post model**

```
class Post extends Eloquent{

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }
```

**User model**

```
public function posts(){
    return $this->hasMany('Post');
}
```

**PostsController**

```
public function index()
{

    $posts = Post::with('user')->paginate(25);

    return View::make('index', compact('posts'));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1. Add `favorites` relationship in `Post` model.

```
 public function favorites() {
    return $this->hasMany('Favorite');
 }
```

When querying the Model.

```
 $auth_user_id = Auth::user()->id;

 $posts = Post::with(array('user', 'favorites' => function($query) use ($auth_user_id){
    $query->where('user_id', '=', $auth_user_id);
 }))->get();
```

For more information refer to the eager load constraints,

http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading

Comment: This worked perfectly and exactly how I wanted it. Taking a look at that link. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Adding a many-to-many relationship using the favorites table as pivot would be one approach.

Add favorites relationship in User model:

```
public function favorites() {  
    return $this->belongsToMany('Post', 'favorites');  
}
```

You should then be able to get all favorites by simply accessing

```
Auth::user()->favorites
```

To find whether the current post is a favorite, use

```
$isFavorite = Auth::user()->favorites->has($post->id);
```

Comment: This works but when I query {{ Auth::user()->favorites->has($post->id) }} within my foreach. only the first result is showing. Not even a zero gets return for the other rows in the foreach.